# ActiveX running Issue on Vista

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, windows-vista, activex

I have Installed ActiveX control on windows vista.. using Internet Explorer and cab file.. It is installed.. I have signed the ActiveX with a test certificate.. but IE is not running my ActiveX, but when I launch the IE by right clicking it and then "Run as Administrator" every thing works fine.. This ActiveX is working fine on Windows XP?? Any suggestion???

Comment: Is this a programming question? or a client configuration question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Vista Internet Explorer could be ran in so called **Protected Mode**. In this case the iexplore.exe process has low integrity level and your ActiveX control can write data only to Low Integrity Write Locations. When you run IE as administrator, the integrity level is high and everything works well.

You can read more here:

[Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28VS.85%29.aspx)